# Nicotinic receptors stimulation

Tags: neurology, nervous-system

I came across this question today, it says:

> Nicotinic receptors stimulation is directly responsible for …

I should fill the spaces by one of the following choices:

1. Increasing the excitability of sympathetic postganglionic neurons.
2. increasing the the force of stomach contraction.
3. delaying the emptying of liquids from the stomach.
4. decreasing the excitability of sympathetic postganglionic neurons.

The only article speaking about the nicotinic receptors in my physiology book says that they are cholinergic receptors found in the autonomic ganglia, i.e. they are found on the postganglionic neurons.

So when I tried to solve the question I thought upper three choices are correct answers because stimulating the receptors on the postganglionic neuron will increase its excitability (choice 1).

Also, if that postganglionic was sympathetic the emptying of the liquids from stomach will be delayed  (choice 3).

And, if it was parasympathetic the force of stomach contraction would increase (choice 2).

I am so confused between these choices, and I feel that there is something wrong.

Could someone help me find the correct answer, but put simply please, as I'm just a first-year dental student.

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please feel invited to take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and to read the [help documents](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).